# Combo/DropDown with tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've been trying to use Combotree (http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/combotree.php) to create a dropdown with hierarchical data, however this component has some bugs and is not fully compatible with jqGrid.

The column with this Combotree component is called AreaId and it uses a custom formatter to display the AreaName when not in edit mode.

I'm using the editoptions: { custom_value / custom_element } to create this component, however it cannot select the current item as the value is a number and I have used the  custom formatter to display the AreaName instead of the AreaId.

I need to select one of the items in the Combotree to be able to get the AreaId instead of AreaName.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok, question updated.